# Elixir's comeonin does not seem to be checking hashes correctly

Tags: hash, elixir, phoenix-framework

So I recently decided I wanted to learn Elixir for the new year, and have been going through the Phoenix framework's book on how web development works in Elixir.

So far I am really enjoying it, and am already starting to love the language.  I've come across a few issues with the Come-on-in package though.

One was compiling it, which is fine.  But I am wondering if it is causing problems, the issue is I am having trouble figuring out how to debug this issue.

```
defmodule Rumbl.Auth do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts) do
    Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
  end

  def call(conn, repo) do
    user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)
    user    = user_id && repo.get(Rumbl.User, user_id)
    assign(conn, :current_user, user)
  end

  def login(conn, user) do
    conn
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
  end

  def logout(conn) do
    configure_session(conn, drop: true)
  end

  import Comeonin.Bcrypt, only: [checkpw: 2, dummy_checkpw: 0]

  def login_by_username_and_pass(conn, username, given_pass, opts) do
    repo = Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
    user = repo.get_by(Rumbl.User, username: username)

    cond do
      user && checkpw(given_pass, user.password_hash) ->
        {:ok, login(conn, user)}
      user ->
        {:error, :unauthorized, conn}
      true ->
        dummy_checkpw()
        {:error, :not_found, conn}
    end
  end
end
```

That is the code, and everything is compiling and I can see it's being sent through correctly.  But for some reason the password is never being resolved.  I made another user with the password "password" and even did something like this:

```
checkpw("password", "$2b$12$aa4dos3r4YwX7HKgj.JiL.bEzg42QjxBvWwm5M")
```

Just to see if it was how I was passing the information, obviously that is the hash in my database, and that also does not work.  I am at a loss to what I am doing wrong, or since this is my first time using Bcrypt and am not 100% sure how the salting works if it's how I am using the library itself.

I am hashing the passwords with this:

```
defp put_pass_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}} ->
        put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(pass))
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end
```

I've looked over everything I can think of, and it all looks correct, but for some reason Comeonin is not comparing the passwords correctly.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "does not work"? Are you getting an error? I'm not an encryption expert, but based on my own tests, I don't believe `"$12$aa4dos3r4YwX7HKgj.JiL.bEzg42QjxBvWwm5M"` is a valid bcrypt string. Was that a copy paste error or is that actually what is in your database?

Comment: Err that was an error when I pasted it, it's updated now.  But yes that is what is in my database, with the new updated version.

Comment: At one point in the book, they tell you to do something like `config :comeonin, bcrypt_log_rounds: 4, pbkdf2_rounds: 1` into `config/test.exs`. Is it possible you put that into `config/dev.exs` or even `config/config.exs` after you already inserted a user and password into the database? Or is there a possibility that you mistyped that password? Can you do `hash = Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("password"); Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("password", hash)` using `iex -S mix` inside the project?

Comment: Hrmm I see what you are saying but that point is actually a few chapters ahead of where I am in the testing section for Elixir.

I also did the iex -S mix and that is working, so that's good.  The weird part is, I am checking the input via `IO.puts "Given Pass"
    IO.puts given_pass
    IO.puts "User password hash"
    IO.puts user.password_hash` and it looks correct.

Comment: So here's the interesting thing, if I check the password like `Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("password", "$2b$12$aa4dos3r4YwX7HKgj.JiL.bEzg42QjxBvWwm5M")` it does break, which is what I am checking.

Comment: What does "break" mean? You need to give more detailed information.

Comment: Sorry when I said break, it evaluates to false.  So if I run `Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("password"); Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("password", hash)` in `iex -S mix` it evaluates to true.  But if I do `Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("password", "$2b$12$aa4dos3r4YwX7HKgj.JiL.bEzg42QjxBvWwm5M")` like my program is trying to pass it, it evaluates to false.

Comment: If that is the case, I would have to say that you mistyped the password when you first entered it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would've thought too, so I made a few more users, it's happening with all of them.  I am not sure what's going on, but I am just not going to authenticate anyone with this tutorial I think, I'm doing something wrong, and have no idea what it is.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @JustinWood I figured it out, I'm stupid, my database was truncating the passwords so it was never the full hash.  Thanks for your time, if it wasn't for you suggesting the iex -S mix I wouldn't have figured that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I was having was not anything to do with Elixir or the Comeonin library!

I had only allowed a Varchar of 45 for my passwords, and it was truncating the response.  I am just going to leave this here in case anyone does something as silly as this in the future!